# Question about pass by reference (memory address) in Java

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I have a simple IntList class that has an iterativeSize() method.

```
public class IntList {
    public int first;
    public IntList rest;

    public IntList(int f, IntList r) {
        this.first = f;
        this.rest = r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntList L = new IntList(15, null);
        L = new IntList(10, L);
        L = new IntList(5, L);


        L.iterativeSize();
        System.out.println(L.first) // this gives 5 instead of null
    }

 public int iterativeSize() {
        IntList x = this;
        int count = 0;

        while (x != null) {
            count++;
            x = x.rest;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

As I would imagine, the original L should become null, because of the while loop that only terminates when x == null. Since x has the memory address of L, L should have become null after:

L.iterativeSize();

But this is not the case. Why does L not change even though x (which has L's memory address), has become null?

Comment: first can never be null as its primitive type.

Comment: This is an immutable linked list, so nothing changes ever ... 
`iterativeSize()` does not change the state of your object, so after invoking `iterativeSize()` L is the same as before.

Comment: Java doesn't support references to references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntList L;` and `IntList x = this;` are **not the same variable**, even though they hold the same value (a reference to the same `IntList` instance) at one point. Thus when `x` becomes null, that has no impact on `L`.

```
List<String> list1ref1 = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- only one instance created
List<String> list1ref2 = list1ref1; // <-- second reference to same instance

// both variables reference the same instance of the object
// thus they both 'add' to the same instance
list1ref1.add("1");
list1ref2.add("2");

System.out.println(list1ref1); // [1, 2]
System.out.println(list1ref2); // [1, 2]

// 'list1ref2' now does not reference any instance, aka null
list1ref2 = null;

// but `list1ref1` still references that original instance
System.out.println(list1ref1); // [1, 2]
System.out.println(list1ref2); // null
```

Comment: Thank you! Really great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a pointer to an instance of `IntList`. You copy that pointer to variable `x` and change only that pointer itself, not the data. And you do not change `L` in main program, so it remains unchanged, pointing to unchanged data. You should write `L = L.rest` in your *main* function if you want to destroy something.

Answer (score 0):

You use x as a pointer to step over different instances of the IntList, but it does not change the value of L. First: L and x are in different scope. You only can change the value of L inside the main method since its scope is there.
Second: To change the value of L you need an explicit value allocation command, like L = something.

Comment: x.first = 1000; 

this will change the value of L.first to 1000, so it's not a matter of scope. Thank you for your response!

Comment: No it does not change the value of L. The value of L is reference to an object, and this is not changed. In this case both x and L is reference to the same object. x.first=1000 changes the value of a field inside this object, but both references (x and L) still points to the same object. Changing the value of L means change which object is referenced by L, and it can be done only when L is in scope.

Comment: Okay! I understand now. Thank you!